# Setup.py not working and seems to install github path rather than library name

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I'm working in a folder corresponding to my github repo `myapp` and attempting to make this an installable library. I have followed the instructions both here: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-a-python-library-7d5aea80cc3f and here https://github.com/MichaelKim0407/tutorial-pip-package.

I have included `__init__.py` in each folder (including root directory). And my setup.py file is as follows:

```
setup(
    name='myapp',
    version=1.0,
    url='https://github.com/myrepo/myapp.git',
    author='Me'',
)
```

I then ran `python -e .` and it returns that the library has been installed successfuly. However importing the library still fails and it appears to have installed the path to the github library instead `-e git+ssh://git@github.com/mygit/myapp.git@62ba3f58b74fc2aca738d1a6114066e1c97dca79#egg=`.

#### Expected Behavior

**Input:** `$ pip freeze | grep myapp`

**Output:**  `myapp==1.0`

**Input:** `python -m "import myapp"`

**Output:** None

#### Actual behavior

**Input:** `python -m "import myapp"`

**Output:**

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'
```

**Input:** `$ pip freeze | grep myapp`

**Output:**
`-e git+ssh://git@github.com/mygit/myapp.git@62ba3f58b74fc2aca738d1a6114066e1c97dca79#egg=`

I don't understand why it appears to be installing this github path rather than the library itself.